# Query console vs .xqy file

Tags: date, marklogic

I am running the following code in the query console:

```
let $age := xs:integer(fn:days-from-duration(fn:current-date() - xs:date(/wl:leader/wl:dob/text())) div 365.25)

return $age
```

And the following in the .xqy file:

```
for $leader in /wl:leader    
let $age := xs:integer(fn:days-from-duration(fn:current-date() - xs:date($leader/wl:dob/text())) div 365.25)
return $age
```

Now, both are similar, however when running on the query console I get the error: arg1 is not of type xs:duration?
I understand the error is cause by the time duration part in 'fn:current-date()', but why do I not face the same issue with .xqy file ?

Comment: You aren't running the same code. Those two code blocks are quite different, and the second is clearly just a subset. Make sure it's 100% the same code in both and submit that here, please. Maybe the cause is $leader is empty, for example.

Comment: I have made a few edits in the question. The second code snippet is working fine, so $leaders is not a problem. Thanks :)

Comment: Got the error. Thanks for your inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mr Hunter points out, the difference in the code explains the error.

The second example passes one leader at a time into the expression.

The first examples passes all of the leaders into an expression that's expecting a single leader.

Hoping that helps,

Comment: It might be worth noting that in MarkLogic using a bare `/` in XQuery is effectively the same as writing `collection()/`. In other words, if you write `/wl:leader`, that will select all `wl:leader` root elements everywhere in your documents database..

Comment: Oh right, in the first code I am passing an entire sequence of one dob at a time. Thanks.